# How can I test a parachain against a production relay chain's live state and configuration?

Tags: parachain, testing, polkadot-launch

It is common to want to be absolutely sure any runtime upgrades and some mission critical extrinsics will work as expected in a safe but otherwise identical environment to a production chain. Testing this locally would be ideal.

Is there a recommended way to *emulate* the configuration and/or the present state, for [`polkadot-launch`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch) for a live relay chain?

Answer (score 3):

### [Fork off Relay Chain](https://github.com/Phala-Network/fork-off-relaychain)

> This script allows bootstrapping a new substrate chain with the current state of a live chain. Using this, you can create a fork of Polkadot, Kusama and other substrate chain for development purposes.

Also useful:

- [`xcm-emulator`](https://github.com/shaunxw/xcm-simulator) - the emulator that takes into account state of a target chain (simulator is now in Polkadot itself).